# GPU hangs and can't decode DVDs on Intel Core i3 HD 2500

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, dvd, xorg.conf

I have an Intel i3-3240T (HD 2500 graphics) running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.  I have two (presumably related?) graphics issues:

- Every so often when using Chrome and e.g. Google Maps or another graphics-heavy webpage the GPU crashes: half the screen diagonally goes black or shows the desktop under the browser, then the whole system freezes for about 30s, then slowly redraws everything and comes back.  Logs show:
  `[drm] GPU HANG: ecode 7:0:0x85ffdff8, in gnome-shell [2203], reason: Hang on rcs0, action: reset` then `i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting chip after gpu hang`
- Neither the default video player nor VLC will play DVDs: both crash either immediately after starting the disc, or will play the menu but crash when playing any of the chapters.  I can get VLC to play DVDs by turning hardware acceleration off and setting the Output Module to X11 or XVideo (XCB).  Using OpenGL as the output module in VLC gives: `traps: vlc[27081] trap divide error ip:7f279491f103 sp:7f27b4108740 error:0 in libgl_plugin.so[7f2794914000+11000]`
  using the "Wayland shared memory" VLC output module gives: `vlc crashed with SIGFPE`

One course of action that suggests itself is trying UXA rather than SNA acceleration but I can't work out where to put the xorg.conf file (searched all the folders in the man page but there are no xorg.conf files there; different people suggest creating it in different folders)

Windows man, new to Linux: any help on where to look next would be appreciated.  It does seem that the graphics drivers are unhappy but I can't work out how to get any more info or how to try and configure them.

Comment: Welcoem to ASkUbuntu! [Wayland isn't Xwindows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/what-is-wayland/4773) which may explain the absence of xorg.conf

Comment: There is nothing to be gained by using hardware decoding for DVD_VIDEO.  Also your chipset may not support in the first place. Run `vainfo` to see..  Your hardware is pretty old, that may account for the OpenGL message, may not. Run vlc from the terminal as vlc -vv to see what it reports. Again using xv for DVD_VIDEO is no worse than OpenGL. . The location to set Intel options would be `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` though you need to create a proper .conf file..

Answer (score 0):

The computer was becoming unuseable; I tried various i915 driver options (i915.enable_rc6=0; i915.enable_fbc=0; UXA and SNA acceleration modes) but couldn't find anything that worked.

(Info on driver config options for i915 can be found by executing `modinfo -p i915`; the options can be set by adding them to the line starting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub`, then saving the file, running `update-grub` and restarting.)

In the end I switched to the modesetting drivers by creating `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "modesetting"
EndSection
```

So far so good.  No noticeable performance issues (it's an old, slow machine anyway), no tearing, and no GPU hangs either.  I can watch YouTube and scroll down graphics-heavy websites again!  Google Streetview still dies after a couple of minutes of use, but at least it doesn't take the whole machine down with it now.